# Trying to connect to two databases, asp.net membership connection throws an exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership

Here is the problem we have:
We have one web application that will be connected to two separate databases. Users from different countries will access the site. Based where you are from you will be connected to one of the two databases. This works fine until two users are logged in and we try to use Membership.GetUser() method. This will through an exception that connection needs to be opened before you can get the user. What is happening, is that connection string is changed and the opened connection is not the same when you run the executeNoQuery() method.

```
try
{
   conn.Open();
   reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

   if (reader.HasRows)
   {
      reader.Read();
      u = GetUserFromReader(reader);
   }
   updateCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

I placed a breakpoint on on conn.open and what happens is after ExcuteReader() the connection string is changed to another connection string and thus the connection is not open and as a result an exception.

Comment: If I am understanding your question, you will need a separate connection for _each database you connect to_.  The code you have provided is, presumably, only opening a connection to once of the databases.

Comment: Yes, there are two connection strings. The code is opening one connection at a time but then when it reaches the ExecuteNonQuery the connection string is for another database. Did I make it clearer?

Comment: Yes, you did make it clearer.  My question is, where/what is your logic for when you switch to either/or connection?

Comment: One site connecting to two different database. A user from Australia and a user from US using the same website but each one needs to connect to a different database. This means the membership is different for each user. The problem occur when the method getuser is hit the same time.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to use the same Connection object, you'll have to close the connection, change the connection string, and reopen the connection.  Simply changing the connection string and then exe executing the command will result in this error.

Update:

You're going to need to set and check the connection string each time you try to open it.  I'd also wrap the connection and command objects in a using() statement to make sure they're disposed of properly when the connection isn't in use.  That should take care of any collisions with other users and eliminate the try/catch statement you have above.  I also added a line of code to check the connection state.  I didn't test this, but it will compile and it should give you a good basis for finishing the the code.

```
// TODO: Set your connection string based on whatever criteria you need.
            string connectionString = String.Empty;

            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[connectionString].ConnectionString))
            {
                if (connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                    connection.Open();

                using (var command = new SqlCommand("commandToExecute", connection))
                {
                    var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                    // Do whatever.
                }
            }
```

Comment: The problem is the method is hit at the same time and while the code is running, the connection string is changed. Not sure I am using the right words but the method is running in parallel. So the second request reaches the updateCmd without the connection being opened. It was opened for the first request. Maybe I should add an illustration of what is happening.

Comment: Unless its a true multithreading application its not happening exactly at the same time so you should be able to capture it.  You can check to see if the connection is open and then close/open it as needed.  Post more code so that we can see this switch and make a recommendation

Comment: Updating my reply above to reflect clarification

Comment: Didnt test yet as the project is on hold. I still need to try it. Sorry for that and as soon I do and it works I will mark it as an answer.